# Changing of www makes session expire

Tags: php, session

I have a merchant website linked to a bank. 
I have defined this success URL in bank :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/deposit.php
```

When the user starts payment process he enters to bank website and after payment he redirects to the success URL in my website.
If a user enters my website with this URL (without www) :

```
http://mydomain.com/
```

The session expires and he should login again. but when he enters with this URL :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/
```

The session will not expire and everything is okey. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: How are you passing on the session? Cookie or URL?

Comment: I would suggest that you change your server set up in such a way as to automatically redirect `yourdomain.com` to `www.yourdomain.com` - web indexing is usually happier about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force www. (or force using just http://mydomain.com aswell) using the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R]
```

The ! in the RewriteCondition tells the server that when the address does NOT equal the following, redirect it to the RewriteRule.

You can find alot more Rewrite tips 'n tricks using .htaccess on the web.

Note: For this to work, you will need to enable this first in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

And make sure your Apache (or other host) configuration supports mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is your session cookie is probably specifically tied to `www.mydomain.com`, so, when you access `mydomain.com`, the browsers chooses not to send the session cookie.

Take a look at `ini_set` function, and the `session.cookie_domain` value.

```
if (count(explode('.', $domain)) > 2) {
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', $domain);
}
```

Comment: Where do i insert this code?  what string i should  set in $domain?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the HTML5 Boilerplate .htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Placing that in your .HTACCESS file should fix the problem. However, someone else will have to elaborate on what exactly is the cause of this problem.

Edit: Seems to me like Pablo Santa Cruz is right.